# SQL - Avoiding Duplicate Primary Keys On Batch Inserts

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update, sql-insert

I'm attempting to batch insert from TableA to TableB, this will (if I can get it working) be then part of a mass UPSERT on a 30/60 minute cycle using 2008R2.

TableB has has a primary key set against it & a unique index.

I cannot drop & recreate with IDENTITY on the int as the table in question is part of a 3rd party application & adding IDENTITY will in turn cause problems with the application.

I was hoping to go down the route of using MAX (even with the issues that could bring but on the whole this shouldn't cause many issues if at all within the environment) however I'm hitting an issue with the unique index on the table using the below;

```
DECLARE @V int
SELECT @V = MAX(PRIMARY_KEY) from TABLEB
INSERT INTO TABLEB ([PRIMARY_KEY],[COL1],[COL2],[COL3])
SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COL1 ASC)) + @V As PRIMARY_KEY,COL1,COL2,COL3
FROM TABLEA
```

The other idea I had was to use a table which held the last used int value, this would updated via a sproc & the sproc output would be the next available.... I don't think this would work either though taking into account what I'm actually trying to achieve.

The end game of the plan was to encompass all (as this is only about 1%) within a half a dozen merge statements, however initially if I can get this at least working it would be a start.

Any ideas or suggestions would be most welcome.

Thanks

Bob

Comment: @AndriyM I did attempt to but a case of long time browser first time poster (& sign up yesterday afternoon) so cannot supply answer until tomorrow at some point. Thanks for the tidy also, not sure how I managed to balls up the second time around.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved what has turned out to be a schoolboy error, I'd overlooked/not noticed a clustered index on another column which I thought at the time was insignificant.... we live & learn.

So to clarify if anyone is interested, the below works as I'd expected with the addition of the column mentioned above... in this dummy scenario it would be col4;

```
DECLARE @v int
SELECT @v = MAX(PRIMARY_KEY) FROM TABLEB
INSERT INTO TABLEB ([PRIMARY_KEY],[COL1],[COL2],[COL3],[COL4])
SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [PRIMARY_KEY] ASC)) + @v ,COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4
FROM TABLEA
```

Thanks

Bob